# Time out request with Here API

Tags: api, tor

I would like to know Here servers automatically reject IPs associated to Tor servers?

Because, I've tried many times to do a request with API (which never answered).

Comment: Why do you want to contact HERE API via Tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking the [HERE FAQs](https://developer.here.com/faqs) it does not say anything about blocking certain IPs, f. ex. from Tor, but it does tell you a bit about limits there adhere to, such as `250,000 Transactions per month`. 
That's probably a good starting point to check for limits of the HERE API.